# Flutter: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter. I don't know how to solve this error. Please help

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _textformField(){

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Color(0xff3a3e3e),
          filled: true,
          hintText: "Search Food",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
_textformField(),


SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: Row(
children: [

  _allCategories(
image: 'images/Ayam-Goreng.png',
title: 'Ayam Goreng',
),

_allCategories(
image: 'images/Ayam-Kari.png',
title: 'Ayam Kari',
),
```

I got "too many positional arguments: 0 expected but 3 found" error when calling `_textformField()` function on line 191.

I tried removing all of the textformField widget but then the error moves to SingleChildScrollView()

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: Row(
children: [

  _allCategories(
image: 'images/Ayam-Goreng.png',
title: 'Ayam Goreng',
),

_allCategories(
image: 'images/Ayam-Kari.png',
title: 'Ayam Kari',
),
```

My _allCategories code:

```
Widget _allCategories({required String image, required String title}){
    return Container(
      height: 130,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 70,
            width: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage(image),
                ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
            ),
          ),
          Text(title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My _bottomCategories code:

````
Widget _bottomCategories({required String image, required String title, required double price}){
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff3c3f40),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(image),
                  radius: 60,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        '\$ $price',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        size: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        size: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        size: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        size: 14,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
````

Comment: can you try with saving and restarting the ide. everything seems fine

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i have done it many times but unfortunately the error still persists

Comment: As for the error message you arent passing anything which should work fine. try using `Error lence` extension on vscode to point the issue